# What's wrong with this use of async await?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise, ecmascript-2017

I am trying to download tracks via the soundcloud API, and then launch a callback once an indeterminant amount of tracks is downloaded. When I run the below code, I see "All done" being console logged before anything else, even though I intend for it to be the last thing... What am I doing wrong?

```
// Deps
import fs from 'fs'
import SC from 'node-soundcloud'
import request from 'request'

// Write mp3 function
function writeMP3(track) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    console.log('Starting download: ', track.title)

    request.get(track.download_url)
    .on('error', err => {
      // reject('Download error: ', err)
    })
    .on('finish', () => {
      () => resolve('Download complete')
    })
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./data/temp/${track.title}_${track.user.username}.mp3`))

  })
}

async function asyncTrackFetch(track) {
  return await writeMP3(track)
}

// Array of promises to callback upon
const trackActions = []

SC.init({
  id: 'MY_ID',
  secret: 'MY_SECRET'
})

SC.get('/tracks', (err, tracks) => {

  if (err) {
    throw new Error(err)
  } else {

    console.log('Tracks fetched: ', tracks.length)

    tracks.map(track => {

      if (track.downloadable) {
        console.log('downloadable')

        trackActions.push(asyncTrackFetch(track))

      }

    })
  }
})

// Perform requests async
Promise.all(trackActions).then(() => {
  console.log('All done')
  console.log(fs.readdirSync('./data/temp'))
})
```

Comment: `SC.get('/tracks',... ` is a callback and you're not waiting for it to resolve before you do Promise.all. You will need to make a promise manually that resolves within `(err, tracks) => { ... }` then await that before you do `Promise.all(trackActions)`

Comment: Ahh, got it. Thanks! Somehow totally slipped my mind that of course an API action is async...

Comment: @MeirionHughes Any idea how to write that, given that the file writing is happening via a stream `pipe`? Can't wrap my head around that.

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.all(trackActions)` waits on whatever promises are in `trackActions`, but `trackActions` is empty at the time you make the call. You're only adding promises to the array after your `SC.get` callback gets called.

Try putting your `Promise.all...` block inside the `SC.get` callback like this:

```
SC.get('/tracks', (err, tracks) => {

  if (err) {
    throw new Error(err)
  } else {

    console.log('Tracks fetched: ', tracks.length)

    tracks.map(track => {

      if (track.downloadable) {
        console.log('downloadable')

        trackActions.push(asyncTrackFetch(track))

      }

    })

    Promise.all(trackActions).then(() => {
      console.log('All done')
      console.log(fs.readdirSync('./data/temp'))
    })
  }
})
```

It's worth mentioning as well that your line `throw new Error(err)` will crash the program since there's nowhere for that error to be caught.

As Antonio Val mentioned, there are better ways to do this. If you promisify the node-soundcloud library then the last part of your code could look like this:

```
SC.get('/tracks').then(tracks => {
  // No need for trackedActions array.
  return Promise.all(tracks.filter(track => track.downloadable)
    .map(track => asyncTrackFetch(track)))
}).then(fetchedTracks => {
  console.log('All done fetching tracks', fetchedTracks)
}).catch(err => {
  // Handle error.
})
```

Or inside an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function),

```
try {
  const tracks = await SC.get('/tracks')
  const fetchPromises = tracks
    .filter(track => track.downloadable)
    .map(track => asyncTrackFetch(track))
  const fetchedTracks = await Promise.all(fetchPromises)

  console('All done fetching tracks.', fetchedTracks)
} catch (err) {
  // Handle error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to move `Promise.all` after `tracks.map` loop finished.

A more elegant solution would be to promisify `SC.get` as well and use `async await` along all your code.

UPDATE:

Couldn't test it so not sure if it works, but it would be something like this:

```
import fs from 'fs'
import SC from 'node-soundcloud'
import request from 'request'

function writeMP3(track) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    console.log('Starting download: ', track.title)

    request.get(track.download_url)
    .on('error', err => {
      // reject('Download error: ', err)
    })
    .on('finish', () => {
      () => resolve('Download complete')
    })
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./data/temp/${track.title}_${track.user.username}.mp3`))

  })
}

function getTracks() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    SC.get('/tracks', (err, tracks) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err)
      }

      console.log('Tracks fetched: ', tracks.length)
      resolve(tracks)
    })
  })
}

SC.init({
  id: 'MY_ID',
  secret: 'MY_SECRET'
})
```

With `async await`:

```
async function start() {
  const tracks = await getTracks();

  for (let track of tracks) {
    await writeMP3(track)
  }
}

start()
.then(() => {
  console.log('All done')
  console.log(fs.readdirSync('./data/temp'))
})
.catch((err) => {
  // insert error handler here
})
```

If you just want to use Promises:

```
getTracks
.then((tracks) => {
  const promiseArray = tracks.map((track) => {
    return writeMP3(track)
  })
  return Promise.all(promiseArray)
})
.then(() => {
  console.log('All done')
  console.log(fs.readdirSync('./data/temp'))
})
.catch((err) => {
  // insert error handler here
})
```